# Can I copy a single shared_ptr simultaneously?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, shared-ptr, atomic

I know that copying and reseting a single `shared_ptr` in 2 separate threads is problematic, but what about 2 threads who try to create a copy of the same `shared_ptr` object. Does it need synchronization? Will the reference counter work properly here?

```
std::shared_ptr<T> global_t(new T());

// Thread 1
std::shared_ptr<T> t1(global_t);
do something with t1

// Thread 2
std::shared_ptr<T> t2(global_t);
do something with t2
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A `std::shared_ptr`'s [refcount is synchronized](//en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/atomic), so concurrent copying is ok (though might be less performant). And the managed object is only freed when its refcount drops to zero.

Comment: and that's exactly why `std::shared_ptr` violates C++ principle "you don't pay for what you don't use". Atomic increment/decrement (used for reference counting) is slower and not required if shared_ptr is used from a single thread, but `std::shared_ptr` doesn't provide a template parameter to use single-threaded reference counter.

Comment: @AndyT Yes. Arguably, it was still the right decision. Maybe. No idea how costly a second variant would have been...

Comment: Nope. Copying and resetting the same `shared_ptr` object from different threads without synchronization is a data race and hence UB. Access to the control block is synchronized, not the `shared_ptr` object itself. That's why there are all those `atomic_*` functions for when you actually need to operate on the same `shared_ptr` object atomically.

Comment: @T.C.: Argh. MT is hard.